# Square bracket $[X]$ with finite fields and polynomial rings

Tags: functions, polynomials

I understand that parentheses are used for functional notation. I do not have any confusion about this one.

However, in some literature, I find square brackets ($[X]$)  after some [finite field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field) notation.

[image]

Source: [Encyclopedia of Cryptography and Security](http://www.springer.com/computer/security+and+cryptology/book/978-1-4419-5905-8), p356

Since, $Q$ has been mentioned as a polynomial, I understand that $F_q[X]$ must be some polynomial. Indeed, the previously cited article in Wikipedia [mentions about polynomial ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field#Irreducibility_of_polynomials). This is [further elaborated here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_ring). This is where things go beyond me.

I was wondering, whether it would be possible to explain a polynomial ring in simple terms. *Yes, something like **Polynomial Ring for Dummies**.*

I hope that I am not asking for too much.

Comment: *"The set of all polynomials with coefficients in the field K forms a commutative ring (or more specifically, an integral domain) denoted K[X] and is called the ring of polynomials over K."* $-$ This is from the Wikipedia article on polynomial rings that you linked to.

Comment: @anon But I was looking for something which I can comprehend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, $F_q[X]$ is not *a* polynomial, but rather the collection of **all** polynomial over the field $F_q$.

The $[X]$ notation denotes the formal variable, $3X^2+1$, for example, is a member of $F_5[X]$.

The set of all polynomials have naturally defined addition and multiplication operations, these make it into a structure called a *ring*, which is why this is also called the polynomial ring $F_q[X]$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. These two articles, http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~mrh/330tutor/ch04s02.html *(last part)* and http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FiniteField.html helped me further understand your response.

Answer (score 2):

If $R$ is a ring, $R[X]$ denotes the ring of polynomials in the indeterminate $X$ whose coefficients are drawn from $R$.